# Handle Max function on Null values or returning multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 table structures below and I need to get results corresponding to maximum verified_dt_tm for a particular event. In case if a particular event has same verified_dt_tm I need to get it on the basis of maximum result_id for that particular event.  I have written an example query below. It works for not null values but doesnt work for NULL. I have used COALESCE for NULL values but that wont work as the outer query will still have verified_dt_tm as null ad they wont match. Below is the detailed description of table.

- order table has 1 entry for every order
- one order can have multiple results. for example blood test can have Basophils count,monocytes count lymphocytes count etc  So one blood test order has 3 or more events corressponding to which i get the results.

Orders Table

```
order_id       order_status
12345          Completed
```

Results Table

```
result_table_id  order_id  event              verified_dt_tm      result_value
98765            12345     Basophils count    22/02/19 11:00      12
87654            12345     monocytes count    21/02/19 15:00      34
76543            12345     lymphocytes count  21/02/19 14:44      35
76542            12345     rbcytes count                          35
76540            12345     rbcytes count                          1
76532            12345     rbcytes count                          3

98765            12345     Basophils count    22/02/19 10:00      12
87654            12345     monocytes count    21/02/19 11:00      34
76543            12345     lymphocytes count  21/02/19 11:44      35
```

Required output

```
result_table_id  order_id  event              verified_dt_tm      result_value
98765            12345     Basophils count    22/02/19 11:00      12
87654            12345     monocytes count    21/02/19 15:00      34
76543            12345     lymphocytes count  21/02/19 14:44      35
76542            12345     rbcytes count                          35
```

Below is the example query. Also, any suggestions on a better query are more than welcome:

```
 select o.order_id
  ,TO_CHAR(r_o.verified_dt_tm, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as verified_dt_tm
  ,r_o.result_val as result
  ,r_o.result_table_id
  ,omf_get_cv_display(r_o.event_cd) as event
  ,omf_get_cv_display(o.ORDER_STATUS_CD) as order_status

from orders o
left outer join (select * from results r where r.event_cd > 0                                
                            and r.VERIFIED_DT_TM = (select max(COALESCE(r1.VERIFIED_DT_TM,to_date('12/31/2099','mm/dd/yyyy'))) from result r1 where r.ORDER_ID = r1.ORDER_ID
                                                    and r.EVENT_CD = r1.event_cd))r_o on r_o.ORDER_ID = o.order_id
```

Comment: What is the logic for choosing only one of three `rbcytes count` records?

Comment: As the verified_dt_tm is null, it would be the value corresponding to maximum of result_table_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ROW_NUMBER` should be viable here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT res.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY res.order_id, res.event
            ORDER BY res.verified_dt_tm DESC, res.result_value DESC) rn
    FROM orders o
    INNER JOIN result res
        ON o.order_id = r.order_id
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim. I also have 5 more tables in my query which I didn't include here. I have to add this as a left join instead of creating it using with. Would this work in that scenario?

Comment: Also, res.* is it supposed to be r.*? I am not sure which table it is referring to

Comment: Yes, I botched the alias and it should be `res` everywhere.  If the CTE be a problem, then you may inline it as a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer by @Tim is perfect according to the sample data. BUT, If one of the record having event as **'rbcytes count' has non-null `verified_dt_tm`** then also it will give output with null `verified_dt_tm` as nulls are considered first in order by desc.

The query should calculate ROW_NUMBER based on an order by `verified_dt_tm desc nulls last`.

Following should work for you:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        RES.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY RES.ORDER_ID, RES.EVENT
            ORDER BY
                RES.VERIFIED_DT_TM DESC NULLS LAST,  -- added NULLS LAST 
                RES.RESULT_VALUE DESC
        ) RN
    FROM
        ORDERS O
        INNER JOIN RESULT R ON O.ORDER_ID = R.ORDER_ID
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    RN = 1;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above, in case if anyone requires to use it as left join with inline subquery :

```
left outer join (SELECT r.RESULT_VAL 
,r.EVENT
,r.result_table_ID
,r.ORDER_ID
,r.VERIFIED_DT_TM
, RANK() OVER(
    PARTITION BY r.ORDER_ID,r.EVENT ORDER BY r.VERIFIED_DT_TM DESC NULLS LAST,r.result_table_ID ) AS RANK 

from results r )r_o on (r_o.order_id = o.order_id AND r_o.RANK = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do this in Oracle without a subquery.  Oracle supports "first" functionality in aggregations, although the syntax is a little clunky:

```
select max(r.result_table_id) keep (dense_rank first order by r.verified_dt_tm desc),
       r.order_id, r.event,
       max(r.verified_dt_tm),
       max(r.value) keep (dense_rank first order by r.verified_dt_tm desc, r.result_table_id desc) as value
from orders o join
     results r
     on o.order_id = r.order_id
group by r.order_id, r.event;
```

From a performance perspective, I have had good results using `keep` for this purpose.